# Closing alertdialog when gridview was clicked

Tags: android

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            Context mContext = getActivity();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.alertdiaolog_main, null);
            GridView gridView2 = (GridView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.alert_gridview);

            gridView2.setAdapter(new AlertImageAdapter(getActivity()));
            gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {  

                }
            });

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Close",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder.setView(layout); 
            builder.show();



        }
    });
```

I have this code. when you click gridView item. an alertdialog will be showns with gridview also. How do I close the alertdialog if the user click on the gridView2 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the `AlertDialog` using `AlertDialog Builder`

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Get the instance of `AlertDialog` using `create`

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

So when required , you can dismiss by calling

```
dialog.dismiss();
```