# Android GridView item click Alert Dialog

Tags: android, gridview, dialog, alert

I have an `AlertDialog` with the `GridView` to choose a color, now I want to close the `AlertDialog` when click item . How can I do?

```
private void Alert_Colori() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker, null);

    GridView gridViewColors = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewColors);
    gridViewColors.setAdapter(new ColorPickerAdapter(this));

    gridViewColors.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //here close the dialog
        }
    });

    customDialog.setView(view);
    customDialog.setNegativeButton("Annulla", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    customDialog.setView(view);
    customDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add

```
final Dialog dialog = customDialog .create();
```

after the line

```
final AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

And then add this in your code

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

to

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     //here close the dialog
}
```

ie, your code for the `ItemClickListener` will be as follows

```
gridViewColors.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
```

Also, please **remember** to change `customDialog.show();` to `dialog.show()`

Comment: You have to change `customDialog.show();` to `dialog.show()`

Comment: Sorry, you have to change everything that uses `customDialog` to `dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Do this - **customDialog.dismiss();**

And try changing

```
final AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
 final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

in your original code like this -

```
private void Alert_Colori() {
 final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker, null);

GridView gridViewColors = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewColors);
gridViewColors.setAdapter(new ColorPickerAdapter(this));

gridViewColors.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     //here close the dialog
     customDialog.dismiss(); 
   }
});

customDialog.setView(view);
customDialog.setNegativeButton("Annulla", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});
customDialog.setView(view);
customDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: remove the space before .dismss()

Comment: check now. Do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

As describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372134 Get the instance of `AlertDialog` using `create`